# TR tag need to eliminate multiple class from Table Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a collection of Table Row (TR) tag in my table. Below is the sample for that

```
<table screen="SpecialInstruction">
<tr class="Header"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Normal"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Footer"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="Total"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to filter out (Header, Footer & Total) from my TableRow ollection. Currently I have used this code `$('table[screen=SpecialInstruction] tr[class!=Header]` and yes its filtering Header class, But i want to eliminate Footer & total class as well. How can i accomplish that ?

Comment: you can chain attribute selectors: `tr[class!=Header][class!=Footer][class!=Total]`

Comment: Why don't just look for "normal" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('table[screen=SpecialInstruction] tr:not(.Header, .Footer, .Total)')
```

Comment: He is trying to delete them. He just want the "normal" one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('table[screen=SpecialInstruction]:not(tr.Header,tr.Footer,tr.total)')
```